# First Tap on Button is not Working Using Kotlin in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

It starts working with second tap/click perfectly. Just the first tap does not work when the  activity starts.

I have tried focus-able attributes both true and false in the button XML code but still it does not work at first click:

```
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
```

Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollButton.setOnClickListener {rollDice()}
        }
    }

    fun rollDice() {
        val resultText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text)
   Toast.makeText(this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()()
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/roll_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/roll_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/roll_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The button should work on first click regardless of focus-able attributes like it does in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set setOnClickListener twice. You don't need to do something like this.

So, you should change this code:

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    rollButton.setOnClickListener {rollDice()}
}
```

To this:

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    rollDice()
}
```